# How to calculate any logarithm without calculator?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I'm not talking about logarithms like $\log_2 \sqrt{32}$, that's really easy for me. I want to calculate without tables logarithms like $\log 17$ or $\ln 912$. Can you tell me how I can do it, please?

Comment: It's so good and it has a proof, but slow. Thank you anyway!

Comment: I appreciate the humid humor of your logo.

Comment: Sometimes it's good to reflect on why one would need to compute logarithms in the way you are requesting. In pure mathematics, $\log 17$ is a perfectly good number, and it is in fact better to write $\log 17$ than $1.30...$, as the latter notation is only as good as the number of digits we supply. Consider the formula for the area of a circle. We don't say area = $3.14r^2$, nor do we say area = $3.1415926535r^2$; we say area = $\pi r^2$, and with good reason. $\pi$ is used to represent the *exact* ratio of a circle's circumference to its diameter.